# How to write code part or method inside .pcf file?

Tags: guidewire

I need to write code like separate module in side pcf file alone. 
Is possible or we need to call existing class's method from action attribute of forward element of Entrypoint pcf file

Comment: It's possible, just initiate your class instance in the 'Variables' tab.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Use code tab in PCF properties, but I suggest you write code in a class and call it from your PCF.

Answer (score 0):

for this scenario, Guidewire had a concept called **PCF Methods**.

A PCF method is a method declared on a given PCF file's Code tab

- The method can be called by properties of PCF file or its widgets.

[image]